# Loading select options after setting value

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

My program flow requires that I first set the value of a select option in the Viewmodel and then I load the available options into the Viewmodel. This causes problems, typically the first available option will be seen in the selection list after this, while the selected option value stays at the specified value.

I was hoping that setting the new "valueAllowUnset" would help, but instead my page becomes unresponsive when using it.

Therefore I currently set the original value again after loading the options. Strangely, this only works when I set the value, set a different value and then set the value again, e.g.

```
self.data()[field](orgValue);
self.data()[field]({});
self.data()[field](orgValue);
```

(I store values for multiple selection lists in the self.data observable and access them with the property index "field".)

I tried to strip this down to a simple JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/HN6DE/), but the behavior does not show there, although the example pretty much resembles my actual application. However, I am using about 30 select lists there.

So I was hoping, that someone can make an educated guess about what goes wrong in my application, I am hoping that the fact that I have to set the original value three times maybe gives a clue.

EDIT: This fiddle demonstrates, that setting the selected option before and after filling the options list does work with "valueAllowUnset": http://jsfiddle.net/timvdh/HT5Tp/

I am using JQuery Mobile with knockout.js and that caused the problem (sorry I did not even think about JQM being the problem in the first place). I am now setting the option before filling the list and after filling the list I call

```
$("#selectmenuID").selectmenu("refresh");
```

to display the option.

The hanging browser was not caused by knockout, there are additional subscriptions to the selectmenus in my app. "valueAllowUnset" changed the behavior of the selectmenus and triggered loops caused by problems in my code.

Comment: In your fiddle, I noticed you're using `<select ... />`, but you really need to use `<select ...></select>`. Try that to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I keep forgetting that. The funny part is: the fiddle works perfectly. I can set the desired option value before or after loading the select options and the value will be retained. It is in my actual application that a) the value will be overwritten by the first loaded select option and b) I can only set the value after loading the options by setting the value three times as shown in the question and c) the "valueAllowUnset" option hangs the browser window. I guess I have to rip my app apart to find out what exactly causes the problem.

Comment: What I'm really curious about is why adding `valueAllowUnset` would hang the browser.

Comment: @Michael: It did not, I edited my question. Thank you for applying yourself to ko development, it is a great tool.

Comment: Thanks for providing the update. So does this mean you've solved the problem?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, it wasn't a knockout.js problem, a jQuery Mobile with knockout problem maybe.